# R dataframe with list of dictionaries as field

Tags: json, r, parsing

I have a data frame with a column called identifiers which contains product identifiers data as a string which is a list of dictionaries.

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  identifiers = c(
  "[{\"type\":\"ISBN\",\"value\":\"9781231027073\"}]",
  "[{\"type\":\"EAN\",\"value\":\"5055266202847\"},{\"type\":\"EAN\",\"value\":\"4053162095984\"}]"),
  id = c(1,2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> test_data
  identifiers                                                                     id
1 [{"type":"ISBN","value":"9781231027073"}]                                        1
2 [{"type":"EAN","value":"5055266202847"},{"type":"EAN","value":"4053162095984"}]  2
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
output_test_data <- data.frame(
  type = c("ISBN", "EAN", "EAN"),
  value = c("9781231027073","5055266202847","4053162095984"),
  id = c(1,2,2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> output_test_data
  type         value id
1 ISBN 9781231027073  1
2  EAN 5055266202847  2
3  EAN 4053162095984  2
```

The closest I got to the solution is to apply the fomJSON function from `jsonlite`.

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(test_data$identifiers[1])
```

or with a loop like this:

```
for (i in test_data$identifiers) {
  print(jsonlite::fromJSON(i))
}
```

However I am struggling to:

1) get it applied to all rows.
2) preserve the information about id, from original data into the results.

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: check out `lapply` ( https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/lapply) to apply a function to multiple values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
df_result <- apply(test_data,1,function(x){
    id_tmp <- x[2]

    df_out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x[1])
    df_out$id <- id_tmp
    return(df_out)
})
df_result <- do.call("rbind",df_result)
```

Comment: Small but important detail :) you also didn't mention that you're reading from a json-file, in your example your data is stored in a `data.frame`. Where does the `id` come from, is this also stored in the data file or is it just the rownumber in the file?

Comment: I'm not reading from a json file, I'm reading from a mysql table which contains that as a text field. I'm running your solution, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Reading chunks of data (e.g. 100k rows per chunk) from the mysql table and applying the solution to the chunk might improve the performance considerably as compared to running it on 22M rows.

Comment: Would it be faster than running the solution on the entire dataframe loaded in memory?

Comment: I assume this could speed up the `apply` and `rbind` since fewer data has to be kept in the memory at a time. For each chunk you would read from mysql, apply the function, write (append) the result to another file, and remove the data from memory. You will have to try out if this is faster.